# JSON parse error: The document root must not follow by other values

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I stumbled upon this issue but i couldnt find a soultion for it. There is a post on StackOverflow with this Problem but the author created the solution himselfe and didnt share it so.

I have Json files which need to be read and then put into a List so i can Instatiate objects with these Datapoints. But I keep getting this Error. Would be very nice if you could help

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[Serializable]
public class InitialOrbit
{
    public string type;
    public Attributes attributes;
    public Relationships relationships;
}
[Serializable]
public class Attributes
{
    public string epoch;
    public string mAno;
    public string inc;
    public string frame;
    public string raan;
    public string sma;
    public string ecc;
    public string aPer;
}
[Serializable]
public class Relationships
{
    public OrbitObject orbitObject;
    public int id;
    public Links links;
}
[Serializable]
public class OrbitObject
{
    public Links links;
}

[Serializable]
public class Links
{
    public string self;
    public string related;
}

public class GetDepris : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string jsonLibraryPath = "myPath";

    List<InitialOrbit> orbits;

    public void ReadOrbitFiles()
    {
        string path = jsonLibraryPath + "Document.json";
        Debug.Log(path);
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
            Debug.Log("json: " + json);

            InitialOrbit initialOrbit = JsonUtility.FromJson<InitialOrbit>(json);

            orbits.Add(initialOrbit);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        ReadOrbitFiles();
    }
}
```

A Json File looks like this:

```
{"data": 
[{"type": "initialOrbit", "attributes": {"epoch": "1965-09-14", "mAno": null, "inc": 63.44, "frame": "J2000", "raan": null, "sma": 6608000.0, "ecc": 0.011, "aPer": 64.0}, "relationships": {"object": {"links": {"self": "/api/initial-orbits/1/relationships/object", "related": "/api/initial-orbits/1/object"}}}, "id": "1", "links": {"self": "/api/initial-orbits/1"}}, 
{"type": "initialOrbit", "attributes": {"epoch": "1965-05-27", "mAno": null, "inc": 51.81, "frame": "J2000", "raan": null, "sma": 6651000.0, "ecc": 0.011, "aPer": 40.0}, "relationships": {"object": {"links": {"self": "/api/initial-orbits/4/relationships/object", "related": "/api/initial-orbits/4/object"}}}, "id": "4", "links": {"self": "/api/initial-orbits/4"}}, 
{"type": "initialOrbit", "attributes": {"epoch": "1965-05-30", "mAno": null, "inc": 51.82, "frame": "J2000", "raan": null, "sma": 6621000.0, "ecc": 0.008, "aPer": 39.0}, "relationships": {"object": {"links": {"self": "/api/initial-orbits/5/relationships/object", "related": "/api/initial-orbits/5/object"}}}, "id": "5", "links": {"self": "/api/initial-orbits/5"}}, 
{"type": "initialOrbit", "attributes": {"epoch": "1965-05-29", "mAno": null, "inc": 95.78, "frame": "J2000", "raan": null, "sma": 6586000.0, "ecc": 0.009, "aPer": 134.0}, "relationships": {"object": {"links": {"self": "/api/initial-orbits/6/relationships/object", "related": "/api/initial-orbits/6/object"}}}, "id": "6", "links": {"self": "/api/initial-orbits/6"}}, 
...
```

It repeads the data with other values 100 times in 1 file

Comment: Is your json complete?

Comment: Your JSON is not valid: https://jsonformatter.org/473ce6

Comment: I see what i did wrong there the json actually starts with {"data": ... so this is fine

Comment: If id Post the whole json here i think it would make the post unnessesary long
As I said there are over 100 single json strings like the one I have posted in 1 file and I have 489 Files to scan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to create one more class, and fix another, also install Newtonsoft.Json for Unity

```
Root root = JsonUtility.FromJson<Root>(json);
```

classes

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Root
{
    public List<Data> data { get; set;}
}

public class Data
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Attributes attributes { get; set; }
    public Relationships relationships { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Links links { get; set; }
}

public class OrbitObject
{
    public Links links { get; set; }
}

public class Relationships
{
    [JsonProperty("object")]
    public OrbitObject orbitObject;
}

public class Attributes
{
    public string epoch { get; set; }
    public object mAno { get; set; }
    public double inc { get; set; }
    public string frame { get; set; }
    public object raan { get; set; }
    public double sma { get; set; }
    public double ecc { get; set; }
    public double aPer { get; set; }
}

public class Links
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string related { get; set; }
}
```

if you want just an InitalOrbit you can get it

```
InitialOrbit initialOrbit = root.data[0];

//or 
InitialOrbit initialOrbit = JsonUtility.FromJson<Root>(json).data[0];
```

And I highly recommend you do install Newtonsoft.Json for Unity and use it instead of JsonUtility

Comment: Thank you very much. That did it for me. Does the json now get split into the single orbit data sets or is one initial orbit now 1 json file data?

Comment: Thank you. Why do you refer the single orbit as `InitialOrbit initialOrbit = data[0];` and not as `Initial Orbit initialOrbit = root.data[0];`?

Comment: @Alec sorry, it was a typo. I forgot that I renamed data to root. See my updated answer

Comment: I have now worked with this but it seems there are no files in root

Comment: @Alec As I told you install Newtonsoft.Json for unity. JsonUtility is outdated but you have a bad property that has an illegal name object.

Comment: Hello there again. I managed to get going and installed Newtonsoft.Json unfortunatly ive never used it bevor and I am not sure how to get to a list of InitialOrbits so i can then go through it and read the attributes, froming a vektor out of them.